# ASP/HTML/VB.NET Button Order

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I have pages(about 13) that have the same code which all work the same but have different button names. I moved the LinkButtonSaveDraft from the top of the list to the bottom of the list before the ImageButtonLock. All but two pages have the button after the HyperLinkSendMail which is where I want the LinkButtonSaveDraft. The 2 pages put the HyperLinkSendMail after the LinkButtonSaveDraft.

Example: other pages(button, button,HyperLinkSendMail,LinkButtonSaveDraft) the 2 pages (button, button,LinkButtonSaveDraft,HyperLinkSendMail)

I am not sure why the pages are putting the button in different order. Let me know if you know something I am missing.

This is the code from the correct layout(from one of the correct pages):

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
 <tr>
<td valign="top">
<asp:Panel ID="buttonPanel" runat="server">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonSave" Text="Save" runat="server" CssClass="gridnav" Height="14px" ValidationGroup="Save" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDate" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" style="position:absolute; visibility: hidden"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonS" Text="S" runat="server" CssClass="gridnav" Height="14px" ValidationGroup="Save" />
    <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="SuspendCalendarExtender" OnClientShown="SuspendCalendarChange" runat="server" Format="MMMM d, yyyy" TargetControlID="TextBoxSDate" PopupButtonID="LinkButtonS" Enabled="True" ></cc1:CalendarExtender>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonUS" Text="US" runat="server" CssClass="gridnav" Height="14px" visible="False" />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonDelete" Text="Delete" runat="server" CssClass="gridnav" Height="14px" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')" />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonRequest" Text="New Request" runat="server" CssClass="gridnav" Height="14px" ValidationGroup="Save" />  
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton122" Text="Report" runat="server" CssClass="gridnav" Height="14px" />  
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton13" Text="R" runat="server" CssClass="gridnav" Height="14px" />  
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonSaveDraft" Text="Save Draft" runat="server" CssClass="gridnav" Height="14px"  ValidationGroup="None" />
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonLock" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/lock.png" Visible="False"  />
</asp:Panel>
</td>
<td valign="top">        
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkSendMail" runat="server" Text="Send Mail" CssClass="gridnav" Height="15px" style="display: inline;" />
        <asp:Label ID="DeleteDraftMessage" runat="server" Text="Note" ForeColor="Red" Visible="False" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td colspan="2"><asp:Label ID="LabelMessage" runat="server" CssClass="SaveMessage" /> <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValSum" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Save" /></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
```

This is the code from one of the pages that have the incorrect order.

```
 <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    <asp:Panel ID="buttonPanel" runat="server">
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonSave" Text="Save" runat="server" CssClass="gridnav" Height="14px" ValidationGroup="Save" />
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonConvert" Text="Convert" runat="server" CssClass="gridnav" Height="14px" ValidationGroup="Save" />
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxSDate" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" style="position:absolute; visibility: hidden"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonS" Text="S" runat="server" CssClass="gridnav" Height="14px" ValidationGroup="Save" />
                        <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="SCalendarExtender" OnClientShown="SuspendCalendarChange" runat="server" Format="MMMM d, yyyy" TargetControlID="TextBoxSuspendDate" PopupButtonID="LinkButtonSuspend" Enabled="True" ></cc1:CalendarExtender>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonUS" Text="US" runat="server" CssClass="gridnav" Height="14px" Visible="False" />
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonDelete" Text="Delete" runat="server" CssClass="gridnav" Height="14px" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')" />
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton135" Text="Report" runat="server" CssClass="gridnav" Height="14px" />
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonSaveDraft" Text="Save Draft" runat="server" CssClass="gridnav" Height="14px" ValidationGroup="None" />
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonLock" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/lock.png" Visible="False" />
                    </asp:Panel>
                </td>
                <td valign="top">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkSendMail" runat="server" Text="Send Mail" CssClass="gridnav" Height="15px" Style="display: inline;" />
                            <asp:Label ID="DeleteDraftMessage" runat="server" Text="(Note: Draft will be deleted after 7 days.)" ForeColor="Red" Visible="False" />
                          </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <asp:Label ID="LabelMessage" runat="server" CssClass="SaveMessage" />
                    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummarySave" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Save" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to fix this problem is made a different  area for the buttons. I did not want to do that but it end up work, and customer was happy.

```
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <asp:Panel ID="buttonPanel" runat="server">
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonSave" Text="Save" runat="server" CssClass="gridnav" Height="14px" ValidationGroup="Save" />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonConvert" Text="Convert" runat="server" CssClass="gridnav" Height="14px" ValidationGroup="Save" />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxSDate" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server" style="position:absolute; visibility: hidden"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonS" Text="S" runat="server" CssClass="gridnav" Height="14px" ValidationGroup="Save" />
                    <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="SCalendarExtender" OnClientShown="SuspendCalendarChange" runat="server" Format="MMMM d, yyyy" TargetControlID="TextBoxSuspendDate" PopupButtonID="LinkButtonSuspend" Enabled="True" ></cc1:CalendarExtender>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonUS" Text="US" runat="server" CssClass="gridnav" Height="14px" Visible="False" />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonDelete" Text="Delete" runat="server" CssClass="gridnav" Height="14px" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')" />
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton135" Text="Report" runat="server" CssClass="gridnav" Height="14px" />
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButtonLock" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/lock.png" Visible="False" />
                </asp:Panel>
            </td>
            <td valign="middle">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLinkSendMail" runat="server" Text="Send Mail" CssClass="gridnav" Height="15px" Style="display: inline;" />
             </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <asp:Label ID="LabelMessage" runat="server" CssClass="SaveMessage" />
                <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummarySave" runat="server" ValidationGroup="Save" />
            </td>
             <td valign="top">
                      <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonSaveDraft" Text="Save Draft" runat="server" CssClass="gridnav" Height="14px" ValidationGroup="None" />
                      <asp:Label ID="DeleteDraftCaseMessage" runat="server" Text="(Note: Draft Cases will be deleted after 7 days.)" ForeColor="Red" Visible="False" />
                </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```